# How do you make a new type of grammar error in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, spell-check, grammar

For example, I come across the phrase "for him to"/"for Daniel to"/"for her to" very often in the non-native English documents I edit and would like to change it to "**so** *he* **can**" and so on. How do I add a new rule to autocorrect every future instance of that phrase in the documents I download to edit?

Comment: I'd be careful of that as a global change. It is not always wrong. "For him to complete the test, he must *xyz*" I'd get some confirmation using examples you see in non-native text & ask on https://english.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in word go to the AutoCorrect tab. In the "replace" box type the phrase you want to edit. In the "with" box type the correct word and then click add.